# Where do I put bundles my bundle depends upon so Eclipse/equinox sees them?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, equinox

I'm trying to use the eclipse OSGi Framework runtime configuration tool, and only those bundles that came with eclipse are available, so the dependencies of my bundles can not be resolved. - I take it I need to put the bundles I depend upon somewhere where eclipse will be aware of them, so that I may choose them in the run configuration.

Where should I drop them? Into the eclipse/plugin's directory? Is there a better way? How do people handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add your bundles to a new target platform and use that to develop and run against. You can start from scratch or from your existing Eclipse installation. I often just make a directory and pop the bundles I want into it. You can also share .target filed Using a target platform is much cleaner and more flexible than playing around with your eclipse installation.

The tool to create a target platform is under Preferences->Plug-in Development->Target Platform.